# how to get the browser controle from opennetCF

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, opennetcf

HI..

i want to get the browser control from opennetCF..can any one please suggest me were i have to download the OpennetCF SDK.. and how to use it to get the browser control from it,,
i m new to opennetCF.. please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can download the OpenNETCF Smart Device Framework [here](http://opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx), but the web browser control is not part of it anymore, as this is now a standard .NET CF control (from v2.0 onwards) as can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) (includes some sample code on how to use it).

Comment: The older SDF code with the browser control is still available at the bottom of the SDF download page as well.

Comment: ya.. thanks tomlog and ctacke..
i tried both.. but i found web-browser in older version.. its very similar to .net CF control.. not much changes have been done like getting web page document and all.. :-(